# best matching overloaded method is not being called

Tags: vb.net

I have the following methods:

```
  Public Function RenderRateTable() As String

  Private Function RenderRateTable(ToddVersionedObject As ToddVersionedObject, 
                                   FieldInfo As FieldInfo) As String

  Private Function RenderRateTable(ArrayIndexes As List(Of ArrayIndexesAttribute.ArrayIndex), 
                     ThreeDimensionalArray As ThreeDimensionalDecimalArrayType) As String

  Private Function RenderRateTable(ArrayIndexes As List(Of ArrayIndexesAttribute.ArrayIndex), 
                                TwoDimensionalArray As ArrayOfDecimalArraysType) As String
```

Note that the types that I'm overloading (`ArrayOfDecimalArraysType`, `ThreeDimensionalDecimalArrayType`) are not classes that inherit from the same base class. They are different structures that don't inherit from anything. They were written by someone else and I can't change them.

When I call it **from within the same class** like this

```
Dim MyThreeDimensionalDecimalArrayType As ThreeDimensionalDecimalArrayType
RenderRateTable(MyArrayIndexes, CType(MyThreeDimensionalDecimalArrayType, Object))
```

it doesn't go to the right method. It just goes to `RenderRateTable()`.

What's even stranger is, the call is made with two arguments (parameters), but these are (ignored?) and it calls a method that takes no parameters and no run-time error is thrown!

I have `Option Strict Off` and the variable I'm passing to the parameter `ThreeDimensionalArray` is of type Object.

I'm trying to get it to where I have a bunch of overloads and it picks the right method based on the type of the `Object` passed.

Polymorphic method calling instead of an `Select Case` statement. I hate conditional blocks like that.

**UPDATE**

I got the code working by declaring the overloads `Public`, but I still don't understand:

1. Why the dispatcher wouldn't find the right `Private` method when the
   call is within the same class.
2. Why the dispatcher would call a method with no parameters when the call is made with 2 parameters, and not throw an error.

Comment: Do you intend to have `RenderRateTable()` as `Public` and the rest as `Private`? `Option Strict On` might have pointed out that as a problem.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, Oh yeah, that's why it's not working. When you do this, every overload candidate has to be public. Can you post an answer as such you you can get some points?

Comment: I've made it into an answer for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `RenderRateTable()` as `Public` and the rest as `Private`, which will prevent it from being able to use the correct overload when called from outside the class.

It is very likely that `Option Strict On` would have pointed out that as a problem: I recommend that you use it to make your programming endeavours easier :)

Comment: You helped me get it working, which is the main thing. But what's not intuitive here, and the reason for the question in the first place is, the call is from **within the same class**! I still don't understand why the dispatcher does not find it. I have it working, but I still don't see why private wouldn't work.

Comment: @toddmo From the question, "the variable I'm passing to the parameter ThreeDimensionalArray is of type Object." This may be hindering the overload selection too. I was somewhat hoping that you would use Option Strict On and correct that problem before I had to figure out a good explanation...

Comment: This won't compile with `Option Strict On`. It gives error `Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to '<each type I'm trying to provide overload for>'.` I'm actually calling that parameter with the result from `FieldInfo.GetValue`, which returns an `Object`.

Comment: You can do an explicit conversion with, e.g., `DirectCast(someObject, ThreeDimensionalDecimalArrayType)`, although ideally `someObject` would have been of the correct type in the first place.

Comment: Right, I could. But I'd have to have a `Select Case` and check the type and convert to the exact type in each `Case`. That would make it work with `Option Strict On`. That's what every other programmer in the world would do, but unfortunately, I can't  stomach that. I hate `Select Case` when polymorphism is possible. `Select Case` would repeat the method call in each `Case`. I am OCD about DRY.